# WebStorm functional snippet React

Tags: reactjs, templates, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, code-snippets

Does anybody knows what the shortcut is for React functional components snippet in WebStorm?

So far I only found shortcut for class components.

Answer (score 67):

Please try `rsf` - it creates a code like

```
import React from 'react';

function Func(props) {
  return (<div></div>);
}

export default Func;
```

[image]

Answer (score 48):

I use the `rsc` live template a lot for new components.

This creates code like:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
        
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Apart from that I created my own live template in the JavaScript category **for creating arrow functions** to save even more time, which creates code like:

```
const myFunction = () => {
    
};
```

Just add a new Live Template under the JavaScript category with this template text:

```
const $1$ = () => {
    $END$
};
```

And make sure to set `applicable in` to `JavaScript and TypeScript` and select the checkboxes for:

- statement
- top level statement

Comment: why did you also create you Live Template? it seems to me it does the same thing as `rsc`

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo hi, i created that just for an arrow function. `rsc` always creates the whole block for a component with import and export statements, and I didn't find any existing template which just creates an arrow function.

Comment: Isn't `arf` doing this?

Comment: @user2078023 hi, I don't see any live template like that in WebStorm version 2020.3.3 which I use.

Comment: @PhilO. I went to Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates -> JavaScript and it is the 1st one. See image here: https://paste.pics/GA3HW

Answer (score 9):

You can configure your own templates in the web-storm by your own key word

go to `settings -> editor -> live templates`

[image: live Templates]

1. Selecting `React`, on the right side press the `add button` or `alt + insert` to create a new template key bindings are based on Linux system
2. Click Live template it will open a pane on below[image: Live Template pane]
3. Add your desired abbreviation in my case i wanted a arrow function with export so i added `rafce`, description is optional
4. In the live template paste your desired format of code generation for your abbreviation

***Example:***

```
// Created on $DATE$ by $USER$:  for project $project$

import React from 'react'

const $FileName$ = () => {
  return (
    <div>$FileName$</div>
  )
}

export default $FileName$
```

`${var_name}$ can be used to describe a inbuilt function on the ide or your custom variable`
for more reference refer the webstorm documentation on inbuilt functions for live templates [webstorm live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/template-variables.html#predefined_functions)

5. You can edit these `variable declarations` on `edit variables` to get your desired behavior
6. Variable declaration for above template
   [image: Variables declaration for templates]
7. Set the application context to java script and type script  click save and apply your template is ready

Comment: Wow, I never knew about these options before seeing your post!  Very helpful and cool!  I always wondered how people were able to get the filename to auto-populate into the component name, now I know!  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

i. `rsf` - Creates a stateless React component as a named function without PropTypes.

```
import React from 'react';

function AppComponent(props) {
    return (
        <div></div>
    );
}

export default AppComponent;
```

ii. `rsfp` - Creates a stateless React component as a named function with PropTypes.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

AppComponent.propTypes = {
    
};

function AppComponent(props) {
    return (
        <div></div>
    );
}

export default AppComponent;
```